# Better responsive street view cardinal direction buttons

Tags: css, flexbox

The context

In a hybrid Android app I am getting images for the current location of the user courtesy of the Google Streetview API.  What I want to be able to do is to provide a set of four buttons pointing to four cardinal directions - I think of these as Up, Down, Left, Right as opposed to North, South etc since the top of the phone screen will not necessarily point "north".  Here is how I have done this for now

```css
.lrdiv{display:flex;}
.ldiv,.rdiv
{
 flex:1;
 text-align:left;
 vertical-align:middle;
 height:2em;
 line-height:2em;
}
.rdiv
{
 text-align:right;
 padding-left:0;
}
.upddiv
{
 text-align:center;
}
#mapJog
{
 padding:0.5em;
 padding-left:80%;
 text-align:right;
 border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height' />

<div id='mapJog'>
<div class='upddiv'>
&#9650;
</div>
<div class='lrdiv'>
<div class='ldiv'>
&#9668;
</div>
<div class='rdiv'>
&#9658;
</div>
</div>
<div class='upddiv'>
&#9660;

</div>
</div>
```

The intent here is to provide a street view 200m to the left/right/above/below the current position depending on which of these buttons is clicked.

The red border has been left in to make the result easier to visualize.  Whilst this is the layout I am after I am concerned that I have not adequately addressed the issue of being able to detect tap events (think fat fingers) on the four buttons at different screen sizes.  Hopefully,someone here will be able to suggest improvements which ensure that this always happens irrespective of screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to use pseudo element to extend an elements *clickable* area.

```js
(function(w, d, last) {
  w.addEventListener("load", function() {
    
    d.getElementById('mapJog').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if(last) {
        last.classList.remove('clicked');
      }
      e.target.classList.add('clicked');
      last = e.target;
    });

  });
}(window, document));
```

```css
.lrdiv {
  display: flex;
}

.ldiv,
.rdiv {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.rdiv {
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.upddiv {
  text-align: center;
}

#mapJog {
  padding: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 80%;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#mapJog div:not(.lrdiv) {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#mapJog div:not(.lrdiv)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;  
  pointer-events: auto;
}
#mapJog div.upddiv::after {
  width: 50%;
  height: 220%;
}
#mapJog div.ldiv::after {
  left: 20%;
}
#mapJog div.rdiv::after {
  left: 80%;
}
#mapJog div.clicked:not(.lrdiv)::after {
  background: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height' />

<div id='mapJog'>
  <div class='upddiv'>
    &#9650;
  </div>
  <div class='lrdiv'>
    <div class='ldiv'>
      &#9668;
    </div>
    <div class='rdiv'>
      &#9658;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='upddiv'>
    &#9660;
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Extending the clickable area by using the `:before`  or `:after` pseudo-elements is one neat idea!